# Update 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.1.1 Magento Mobile

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, upgrade, magento-connect, ce-1.9.1.1

I try to update our Magento store from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.1.1.
Everything succeed except the Magento_Mobile package.

I get this error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Magento_Mobile failed: Package release 'Magento_Mobile' not found on server

Tried to set Mage_XMLConnect.xml to true, but that also does not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @KeyurShah Sorry, but it did not helped me

Answer (score 1):

In magento 1.9.1 `Mage_XmlConnect` is by default in disabled mode so i think it create issue.

Comment: Tried that, but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `mage` to update magento. You don't want to update your live system.

Instead load the current source from magento.com and copy it over your old install.

Make sure, that you replace the whole core and remove all old core modules and `app/etc/module` xml files.